# Java. Как изменить DXF файл?

Tags: java, чпу, dxf

Мне необходимо изненить `DXF` файл.. Все рекламмируют библиотеку `kabeja`. С горем пополам я научил её читать нужные мне файлы, а вот чтобы сохранить.. Не поверю, что библиотека, которая позволяет прочитать и изменять `DXF` файлы - не умеет их сохранять..

Я потратил довольно много времени на исследование - но нашёл только "обёртки от конфет".

Подскажите, как можно сохранить файл в формате `DXF` в `Java`, неважно при этом какая будет библиотека.

`kabeja` я прилепил к проекту как `jar` файл, и у меня только декомпилированные классы, что сильно затрудняет процесс поиска проблемы.

Прочитать `DXF` я смог, все нужные преобразования я сделал, а как их записать обратно в новый файл - не нашёл.

Нашёл несколько примеров и инструкций:

```
//how to save
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76266749/kabeja-0-4-how-to-save-changes
https://github.com/AlessioWang/DxfWriter
https://sourceforge.net/p/kabeja/discussion/510352/thread/e6ed0c2f/
```

Из интересного есть `DXFGenerator`, но он отсутствует в версии 0.4

Подскажите пожалуйста какие варианты решения могут быть?

Или любой генератор, который сделает `DXF` файл...

Я могу написать свой интерпретатор готовых `POJO` в текстовый файл, **но подозреваю там куча проблем будет**. Присылайте любые идеи!

ps: вижу голоса за закрытие, отпишитесь пожалуйста в комментариях за что.. Информации об этой проблеме есть много в инете, а вот решений чуть.

Comment: В чем сложность? dxf это текстовый формат. Читаете спецификацию и пилите свой интерпретатор :)  Эту библиотеку не юзал, но разве вы не можете получить отредактированные данные и просто сохранить текст в формате dxf?

Comment: @ПоляковРоман Были такие мысли, но это велосипед... К тому же DXF формат не так прост, чтобы с ним как с текстом обращаться. Там глубина реза, шрифты, множество слоёв, разные цвета, бесконечное количество поддержки разных типов объектов. Мне нужно просто открыть - кое что поменять и закрыть, по возможности не касаясь всего остального. И я люблю велосипеды, но для себя - а тут хочется красивее сделать

Comment: >>Читаете спецификацию и пилите свой интерпретатор :) - просто превосходный совет. Звучит примерно как: "Не нашли за 6 минут решение в интернете - пишите свой аналог машинного обучения с поддержкой ИИ"

Comment: Это шутка) Не пробовали библиотеки для python? Там есть из чего выбрать, а для этой библы написано, что она помогает анализировать dxf и выводить все это в svg, что странно.

Comment: @ПоляковРоман можно и питон попробовать, но у меня опыта там немного... Попробую ради эксперимента